# Web Forms are ignored after clicking on downloadable files

Tags: download, webforms

Hello I'm working with a broken web form, the issues is that the current form would only pop up after loading the PDF in a different window tab.

The form is completely ignored after clicking the PDF url, which is redirected into a new tab, without giving any information. I'm working with a drupal site which is version 8.4. I've researched modules and only found web form modules that support Drupal 7 and below. Is there way to fix this current one? I'm still researching on other options.

here's the link to the site https://adnetcmm.com/resources

---

```
<div class="overlay" style="display:none">
<div class="contactForm" style="display:none"><b><span class="close">✖</span> </b>

<div>
<p><b>Please submit form to download Pdf</b></p>
</div>
<b> </b>

<form action="#" method="post"><b><input class="inputc" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text" value="" /> <input class="inputc" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text" value="" /> <input class="inputc" name="phone" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" placeholder="Phone" required="" type="text" value="" /><textarea class="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Comments.." required=""></textarea> <input class="contbtn" id="ajaxpdf_submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;</b></form>
<b> </b></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no idea what your expected outcome is or what's actually happening.

Comment: I provided a link of the resources page of the site, I'm working on. When ever I click on one of the files below listed on the resources page the web form only appears after viewing the PDF. I want to fix it so the web form appears first than the other way around.